# How to make a background match objects in the foreground?

Tags: games

If you have a game, in which your character moves around, and cannot move past walls, and has to collect keys, it may look like this:

[image]

Now the question is, what steps can one take which would ensure that the background and the foreground (the walls, keys) match each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "Match each other?"

Comment: So they go well well to together. Black and yellow wouldn't go well together.

Comment: Personally with my experience in game development I'd try to make them _not_ match so much. It can be difficult to see an element if it blends in too much, then the player gets annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

Make it light gray instead of red. That way its the same color scheme and matches.